# Draw buffer around points considering slope in QGIS

Tags: qgis, area, slope, surface, shape-area

I generated random points on a map. Around each point I would like to draw a circular buffer which considers the slope in that area, and within these circular buffers I would monitor tree height in the field.

It is very important for the polygons to consider the slope because I would always like to have the same surface area in each polygon. So I assume that when drawing a circular buffer it will turn out ellipsoidal on a area with a slope.

Comment: I suppose you could create ellipsoids around your points, using the direction of the slope for orientation, and its steepness as a factor for calculating the minor extent of the ellipsoid. Applied trigonometrics.

Comment: in most cases the vertical variation will be negligible for the area, unless you are looking at very steep slopes over very short distances

Comment: The monitoring plots will have a radius of just 8-15meters and the terrains that we are working in have steep slopes. So unfortunately we found out that we cannot neglect the slopes.

Comment: @Erik is there a way to do this automatically. It seems like such an easy and basic necessity. I really only want to draw a polygon of a specified radius considering the slope.

Comment: I told you how to do it automatically? What else do you need?

Comment: @Erik sorry, I mean that instead of having to do this manually for all points I would like to just give QGIS the command to create a buffer around features directly from a DEM.

Comment: Then you need to create a model, which incorporates the described operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about the math, but the steps before it should work. I'm using 50 m buffer radius.

1. Calculate a aspect raster
2. Calculate a slope raster
3. Sample raster values twice to get aspect and slope as attributes on each point
4. Field calculate the ellipse major axis: `cos(radians("slope1"))*50`
5. Geometry by expression:  `make_ellipse($geometry, "major", 50, "aspect1")`

For some reason I cant get Geometry by expression to work without the Field Calculator step.

[image]