# Distort buffer on slope direction in QGIS

Tags: polygon, slope, aspect

I'm an archaeologist and an average QGIS user, not advanced at all.

I'm studying a method for the mountain archaeological contexts. My aim is to define some influence areas around the sites and correlating them to the new planned constructions to evaluate archaeological risk.

If the area is located in a flatland zone the buffer should be circular (the higher the importance the bigger the radius), not a big issue.
Things get different in the mountain areas, especially because the findings slide on the slopes and move to the bottom of the valleys throughout the centuries, so the influence area won't be circular but a distortion of it following the slopes inclination.
For example if a site is on a hillside, the buffer should be modified extending it in the downhill direction, reducing it extension on the uphill.

To do that I need to create my circular buffers (like I were on a flat ground), then reshape them following the inclination of the slope. I looked but I didn't find a plugin or a workflow suitable for that. I imagined a workflow, but I don't know how to implement it:

1. Tessellate the polygon in small polygons (perhaps with Voronoi algorithm)
2. Apply to each vertex the corresponding slope direction vector in overlay area
3. Define a factor (vector module) to manage the intensity of the distortion (as realistic as possible)
4. Create a new layer with the external boundary of the distorted output I got.

In my opinion, the tessellation is requested to keep trace in the transformation of the inclination located within the polygon, so we don't work only on the boundary. That because the boundary could be in a relatively flat ground that could be passed over by the uphill polygon vertex (with an higher sliding vector).

Those steps are for me theoretical and I don't know how to apply them. It is likely a clumsy process that perhaps could be easily done with a plugin or a different workflow.

Here's an idea of my purpose drawn manually:

[image: green point ► site location, red ► normal buffer, blue ► distorted buffer on slope]

green point ► site location - red ► normal buffer - blue ► distorted buffer on slope

My aim is the blue area.
Is there a plugin to do so?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, your Question doesn't contain a question.  We are a *problem-solving* site, but all you have here is a long list of tasks you would like to accomplish, with no indication of an attempt or a problem when doing so. Give it a shot, and let us know what  problem you encounter.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423119/draw-buffer-around-points-considering-slope-in-qgis

Comment: you are perfectly right, especially because I mistakenly cut away the last lines (the one with the question). Forgive me for have being a little to wordy (I tried to describe my hypothesis on how to solve it). The question was: is there a plugin (or a quick method) to reshape a polygon following the inclination of the ground? Thanks in advance for any advice you want to give.

Comment: Thank you BERA for the suggestion. I already checked that post, but what I'm trying to do is the opposite. The subject of the post are round buffers perfectly orthogonal to the terrain surface (so you can see them as ellipses from the top view of the canvas). My purpose was to stretch the buffer along the hillside, I'll post a picture drawn manually of what I'm trying to do

Comment: I posted it to get you started. Your question is very broad and will probably get closed because of lack of effort. Add your attempt and where you got stuck

Comment: Ok, understood.  I'll try and let you know.

Comment: I'm not very skilled, but I'll try, let's see what comes out of it.